# FastAdapter flickers after loading from LiveData even though the data stays same

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, fastadapter

For the question I have prepared [a simple and working example at Github](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/tree/master/TopPlayers):

[image: app screenshot]

My example app downloads a JSON array containing top 30 players in a game using okhttp and stores them into SQLite Room. In the [fragment](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/tree/master/TopPlayers/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/topplayers) I observe the corresponding `LiveData<List<TopEntity>>` object and update the FastAdapter instance:

```
public class TopFragment extends Fragment {
    private final ItemAdapter<TopItem> mItemAdapter = new ItemAdapter<>();
    private final FastAdapter<TopItem> mFastAdapter = FastAdapter.with(mItemAdapter);

    private TopViewModel mViewModel;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TopViewModel.class);
        mViewModel.getTops().observe(this, tops -> {
            mItemAdapter.clear();
            for (TopEntity top: tops) {
                TopItem item = new TopItem(top);
                mItemAdapter.add(item);
            }
        });

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_fragment, container, false);
        mProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFastAdapter);

        fetchJsonData();

        return v;
    }
```

My problem is: the recycler view flickers once - every time the data is downloaded.

Even though the top 30 does not change often, i.e. the data stays same.

When I look at the example app in the excellent [FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter) library by Mr. Penz, I do not see any flickering there.

**UPDATE:**

I've got [a hint](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/issues/737) that the flickering is obviously caused by calling `mItemAdapter.clear();` in the `onChanged` method and I should use DiffUtil class instead.

So I have added a new class:

```
public class DiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {
    private final List<TopItem> mOldList;
    private final List<TopItem> mNewList;

    public DiffCallback(List<TopItem> oldStudentList, List<TopItem> newStudentList) {
        this.mOldList = oldStudentList;
        this.mNewList = newStudentList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return mOldList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return mNewList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        TopItem oldItem = mOldList.get(oldItemPosition);
        TopItem newItem = mNewList.get(newItemPosition);

        return oldItem.uid == newItem.uid;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        TopItem oldItem = mOldList.get(oldItemPosition);
        TopItem newItem = mNewList.get(newItemPosition);

        return oldItem.elo == newItem.elo &&
                oldItem.given.equals(newItem.given) &&
                //oldItem.photo != null && oldItem.photo.equals(newItem.photo) &&
                oldItem.avg_time != null && oldItem.avg_time.equals(newItem.avg_time) &&
                oldItem.avg_score == newItem.avg_score;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return super.getChangePayload(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition);
    }
}
```

And then I am trying to use it in the `onChanged` method instead of just calling `mItemAdapter.clear()` but the RecyclerView stays empty even though the `tops` has elements:

```
mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TopViewModel.class);
mViewModel.getTops().observe(this, tops -> {
    List<TopItem> oldList = mItemAdapter.getAdapterItems();
    List<TopItem> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TopEntity top: tops) {
        TopItem item = new TopItem(top);
        newList.add(item);
    }

    DiffCallback diffCallback = new DiffCallback(oldList, newList);
    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback);

    mItemAdapter.getAdapterItems().clear();
    mItemAdapter.getAdapterItems().addAll(newList);
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(mFastAdapter);
});
```

**SHORT SUMMARY OF MY PROBLEM:**

My real app uses `FastAdapter` for several reasons and I am looking for a way to "marry" it with [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) in order to eliminate the one-time flickering when the data is downloaded over HTTPS and updated in Room.

Comment: In unit or instrumented tests, does `diffResult` seem to get calculated correctly? If so, then perhaps there is some issue with `DiffResult` and `FastAdapter` (I have not used `FastAdapter`, so I have no experience with it).

Comment: Does your code highly depend on `FastAdapter`? I mean is it possible to you to change it? As I read your code and related parts of `FastAdapter`, I think the source of this issue comes from thinking behind `FastAdapter` architecture.

Comment: Thanks for asking, but I would like to use FastAdapter, because [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.slova) uses its search and filtering capabilities in several fragments and also it uses MaterialDrawer - which is also based on FastAdapter. My target is to get FastAdapter to work either with DiffUtil or with its own [FastAdapterDiffUtil](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/issues/737) - but I haven't succeeded with either path yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[With the help of FastAdapter author](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/issues/737) I have been able to eliminate the one-time flickering by adding an identifier to my [TopItem](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/blob/master/TopPlayers/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/topplayers/) being displayed in the RecyclerView:

```
@Override
public long getIdentifier() {
    return uid;
}
```

And by using the FastAdapterDiffUtil in my [TopFragment](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/blob/master/TopPlayers/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/topplayers/):

```
mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TopViewModel.class);
mViewModel.getTops().observe(this, tops -> {
    List<TopItem> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TopEntity top: tops) {
        TopItem item = new TopItem(top);
        newList.add(item);
    }

    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = FastAdapterDiffUtil.calculateDiff(mItemAdapter, newList);
    FastAdapterDiffUtil.set(mItemAdapter, diffResult);
});
```

Comment: What if identifier is a string? I.e. a guid. There's no good way to hash it into a long without collision.

Comment: I just use `public long getIdentifier() { return word.hashCode(); }` it seems to work for me in an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.slova) with 111867 words

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to avoid blinking is to disable the `RecyclerView`'s `ItemAnimator`.

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right solution. If some items move up/down I would still want the re-arrange animation. It just should not blink if it's the same item.

Comment: @mliu: You are right. I know. This issue comes from `mItemAdapter.clear();` in the library that I think it is not right. However, this solution does not cover the library problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning some marker object from getChangePayload() method.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Object getChangePayload(final int oldItemPosition, final int newItemPosition) {
    return mNewList.get(newItemPosition);
}
```